# Remove leading white space in Ruby hash value

Tags: ruby, hash, strip

I'm working on an example problem from Chris Pine's Learn to Program book and I'm having an issue removing white space in my hash values.

I start with a txt file that contains names and birthday information, like so:

```
Christopher Alexander,  Oct  4, 1936
Christopher Lambert,    Mar 29, 1957
Christopher Lee,        May 27, 1922
Christopher Lloyd,      Oct 22, 1938
Christopher Pine,       Aug  3, 1976
```

Then I go through each line, split at the first comma, and then try to go through each key,value to strip the white space.

```
birth_dates = Hash.new {}

File.open 'birthdays.txt', 'r' do |f|
  f.read.each_line do |line|
  name, date = line.split(/,/, 2)
  birth_dates[name] = date
  birth_dates.each_key { |a| birth_dates[a].strip! }
end
```

But nothing is getting stripped.

```
{"Christopher Alexander"=>"  Oct  4, 1936", "Christopher Lambert"=>"    Mar 29, 1957", "Christopher Lee"=>"        May 27, 1922", "Christopher Lloyd"=>"      Oct 22, 1938", "Christopher Pine"=>"       Aug  3, 1976", "Christopher Plummer"=>"    Dec 13, 1927", "Christopher Walken"=>"     Mar 31, 1943", "The King of Spain"=>"      Jan  5, 1938"}
```

I've seen a handful of solutions for Arrays using .map - but this was the only hash example I came across. Any idea why it may not be working for me?

UPDATE: removed the redundant chomp as per sawa's comment.

Comment: Your concern is not reproducible. The values in `birth_dates` are stripped.

Comment: By the way, doing `chomp` before `strip` is redundant; `strip` alone is enough.

Comment: Thanks @sawa - I updated the example to remove the redundancy. Though, in my example and the two answers below, terminal is still showing that there's some space in front of the month. Is it just a display issue in terminal?

Answer (score 2):

For parsing comma delimited files i use CSV like this

```
def parse_birthdays(file='birthdays.txt', hash={})
  CSV.foreach(file, :converters=> lambda {|f| f ? f.strip : nil}){|name, date, year|hash[name] = "#{year}-#{date.gsub(/ +/,'-')}" }
  hash
end
parse_birthdays
# {"Christopher Alexander"=>"1936-Oct-4", "Christopher Lambert"=>"1957-Mar-29", "Christopher Lee"=>"1922-May-27", "Christopher Lloyd"=>"1938-Oct-22", "Christopher Pine"=>"1976-Aug-3"}
```

of if you need real date's you can drop the lambda

```
def parse_birthdays(file='birthdays.txt', hash={})
  CSV.foreach(file){|name, date, year|hash[name] = Date.parse("#{year}-#{date}")}
  hash
end
parse_birthdays
# {"Christopher Alexander"=>#<Date: 2014-10-04 ((2456935j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, "Christopher Lambert"=>#<Date: 2014-03-29 ((2456746j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, "Christopher Lee"=>#<Date: 2014-05-27 ((2456805j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, "Christopher Lloyd"=>#<Date: 2014-10-22 ((2456953j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, "Christopher Pine"=>#<Date: 2014-08-03 ((2456873j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}
```

Comment: Is it a CSV if the lines are broken by returns?

Comment: Ran the first option, and it separated things nicely, but it looks like the leading space before the months are [still hanging around](http://cl.ly/image/0E022q3T1s3Y)

Comment: that is because these spaces are in the middle of a string, then you need a regular exspression, i adapted the first part of my answer, is used a - to do the replace but you can use a single space also

Answer (score 0):

I would write this

```
File.open 'birthdays.txt', 'r' do |f|
  f.read.each_line do |line|
  name, date = line.split(/,/, 2)
  birth_dates[name] = date.chomp
  birth_dates.each_key { |a| birth_dates[a].strip! }
end
```

as below:

```
File.open 'birthdays.txt', 'r' do |f|
  f.read.each_line do |line|
    name, date = line.split(/,/, 2)
    birth_dates[name] = date.chomp.strip
  end
end
```

or

```
birth_dates = File.readlines('birthdays.txt').with_object({}) do |line,hsh|
  name, date = line.split(/,/, 2)
  hsh[name] = date.chomp.strip
end
```

Comment: It runs great, but [I still see the leading whitespace in terminal](http://cl.ly/image/0V220B0t310L).